# Imagick : SVG to PNG conversion giving me blank png image

Tags: svg, imagick

I have a SVG image on this path http://www.quickdesign.com/user-uploads/5555f546857ce-saved.svg

Which i need to convert into PNG for which i am using below code on this php file http://www.quickdesign.com/png.php

```
<?php
$svg_file_name = 'user-uploads/5555f546857ce-saved.svg';
$png_file_name = 'png/converted.png';
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$svg = file_get_contents($svg_file_name);
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg;
$im->readImageBlob($svg);

/*png settings*/
$im->setImageFormat("png32");


$im->writeImage($png_file_name);

header('Content-type: image/png');

echo $im;

$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
?>
```

If i remove the line `$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg;` Then it gives fatal error Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format

Can anyone please help me how to convert above svg image to PNG image using PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you searched for "no decode delegate for this image format" and tried the suggestions, what happened?

Comment: That was fixed by this line $svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg;

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick uses delegates to read some images. It looks like the delegate it is using for SVG files on your system is unable to the SVG file you are telling it to read.

Reading that file also fails on my system due to this bit:

```
<stop fill="url(#svg_14)" stop-color="#A0D9F7" offset="0"/>
```

with the error message:

```
php: unrecognized color `svg_14' @ warning/color.c/GetColorCompliance/1046.
php: unable to open image `svg_14': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2674.
php: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

url support inside SVG files is a bit flaky. It seems that svg_14 is defined at the end of the file. Moving it to the start makes the file be 'readable' but the image looks different to how it should appear.

I would suggest finding out what delegate ImageMagick is using to decode SVG files, which may be found with `convert -list configure` and finding if there is a more recent version of that library which fixes the issue.